# Conditional text replacement

Tags: text-processing

I'm pre-processing some ecommerce product titles, such as:

Input:

```
 1. Jersey Shore: Family Vac Season 2
 2. Robotic Vac Cleaner with Max Power Suction
```

Notice that booth titles have a **Vac** word. I would like to correct the 2nd one, replacing it to **Vaccum**.

Desired output:

```
 1. Jersey Shore: Family Vac Season 2
 2. Robotic Vaccum Cleaner with Max Power Suction
```

I could write a algorithm (for instance checking if the string contains "clean" or "suction"), but first I would like to know if there are any frameworks, libraries, etc that already does this kind of task. Seems to be a commom problem... It could be any language (java, python, c, etc).

Comment: Use a regex if you have not so far: `\bVac(?i)(?=.*(?:Clean|Suction))` => `Vacuum`. Python: `text = re.sub(r'\bVac(?i)(?=.*(?:Clean|Suction))', 'Vacuum', text)`

Answer (score 0):

I could think that you are getting those tittles from an API or are them hardcoded in the site?

If you have it in a JSON format or even in something more simple as an array of strings:

```
var products = [{
  'title': "Jersey Shore: Family Vac Season 2",
}, {
  'title': 'Robotic Vac Cleaner with Max Power Suction',
}]
```

There is a very useful Javascript tool ->

https://fusejs.io/

With it you can search and even specify nice parameters like:
`threshold` -> if you want a perfect match or similar words, etc.

Visit the site the documentation is great.

After that you can use Javascript (String.prototype.replace) `replace` with the word that you want, in this case: `Vaccum`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace

And get your final object or array to be placed on your ecommerce site